# How to use 2 local tables linked with a foreign key in a qcumber test?

Tags: kdb

I have the following test code

```
feature UsingQcumber
    should be able to create 2 tables in a test
        expect the code to run through to the end
            tParent:([id: til 5]; parentData: 5 ? 100);
            tChild:([] parentId: `tParent$ 20 ? 5; childData: 20 ? 1000);
            1b
```

This test is failing with the following

```
file test1.quke
    feature UsingQcumber
        (should) be able to create 2 tables in a test
            - fail | (expect) the code to run through to the end
                error: tParent (line 3)
```

If I remove the foreign key, the test passes. So I expect there is some sort of namespace shenanigans qcumber is using. Also, if I globally assign the tables with `::` then it passes. But what if I want my test to be isolated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you can't set a foreign key (or enumerate symbols) to a local table (or local symbol list) .... it must be a global. So your only option is to create the tParent globally and delete it afterwards.

Note that your tChild table *can* be local, just not the target of the foreign key (or enumeration)